# Memoizing recursive solution with Hashmap causing time limit to exceed for Apple Division CSES problem

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, dynamic-programming, memoization

For solving this problem - [problem set](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1623/), I had earlier used simple recursion, and the code is as follows:

```
public long solve ( int[] arr ) {
    long totalSum = 0;
    long sumCalculated = 0;
    for ( int k : arr ) {
        totalSum += k;
    }
    return findMinDiff(arr, arr.length - 1, sumCalculated, totalSum);
}

/**
 * findMinDiff(arr,n,sumCalculated,totalSum) = { abs(totalSum - 2*sumCalculated, if n == 0,
 *                                              min(findMinDiff(arr,n-1,sumCalculated+arr[n],totalSum), //In subset we considered keeping nth element
 *                                                  findMinDiff(arr,n-1,sumCalculated,totalSum)) // In subset we didn't keep nth element
 *                                              }
 */
private long findMinDiff ( int[] arr, int i, long sumCalculated, long totalSum ) {
    if (i == 0) {
        long val = Math.abs(totalSum - 2 * sumCalculated);
        return val;
    }

    long val = Math.min(findMinDiff(arr, i - 1, sumCalculated + arr[i], totalSum), findMinDiff(arr, i - 1, sumCalculated, totalSum));
    return val;
}
```

The above solution has a time complexity of 2^n and it got accepted. Now, decided to memoize the recursion using a hashMap in java, and the following dp solution is given below:

```
public long solve ( int[] arr ) {
    long totalSum = 0;
    long sumCalculated = 0;
    for ( int k : arr ) {
        totalSum += k;
    }
    HashMap<String, Long> dp = new HashMap<>();
    return findMinDiff(arr, arr.length - 1, sumCalculated, totalSum, dp);
}

private long findMinDiff ( int[] arr, int i, long sumCalculated, long totalSum, HashMap<String,Long> dp ) {
    String key = i +" "+ sumCalculated;
    if (dp.containsKey(key)) {
        return dp.get(key);
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        long val = Math.abs(totalSum - 2 * sumCalculated);
        dp.put(key, val);
        return val;
    }

    long val = Math.min(findMinDiff(arr, i - 1, sumCalculated + arr[i], totalSum), findMinDiff(arr, i - 1, sumCalculated, totalSum));
    dp.put(key, val);
    return val;
}
```

My understanding was that since we are memoizing and returning the memoized solution, this solution should be way faster and much less than 2^n time complexity. But when submitted the dp solution, got a TimeLimitExceeded error. Wanted to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Memoizing can reduce the asymptotic time complexity of the program, but that's not the same thing as being faster for any specific problem.  If program **A** has lower asymptotic time complexity than program **B** then there is some problem size *x* such that **A** is faster than **B** for all problems larger than size *x*, but the smallest such *x* can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Your usage of a `HashMap` (and accompanying boxing and unboxing of primitives) adds a lot of overhead.  As a result, you might well have an execution time penalty instead of a benefit for the problem sizes actually tested.  If you have enough memory for it then you might find that a simple array works better.

Comment: If I am using top down solution, how can I model to store the result in an array instead of hashMap and retrieve it?

If we use bottom up approach, then it seems we can use a 2D array as such to store the values.  But since, top down seems more intuitive, how can we model storage of data in this case?

Comment: A sufficiently large array is a nearly direct replacement for a HashMap.  The array indices correspond to map keys.  The values are the values.  You need at least one distinguished value to mark an array element as notionally empty, but zero works for that in this problem, and you get zero-initialization automatically.  For 20 apples, you should be able to do it with an array having 2^20 elements -- a little over a million, which should be easily accommodated within the problem limits.

Comment: I was using a unique string combination of ith index of array and sumCalculated as a key in the hashMap. We definitely can't use sumCalculated as the index in large array created as replacement for the hashMap because it can exceed 2^20. Was wondering how each index in large array can be exactly used as a key, because I don't think even using the above unique string key and generating index in large array using a hash function will either work here as well.

Comment: In a general sense, I would use an `int` key whose bits encode assignments of apples to the first group, one bit per apple.  But now that I think more about it, I think that memoization may just be an altogether false trail for your particular algorithm.  I'm not seeing how it can reduce the worst-case total number of calls to your `findMinDiff()`.  Consider, for example, cases where for each *i*, the weight of apple *i* is `1 << i`.  Every distinct combination of apples then has a different weight, so memoization does not gain any reuse of partial results.

Comment: As a side note, this problem is equivalent to the [0-1 Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with knapsack size equal to half the total combined weight of the apples.  Perhaps that will give you some insight into efficient ways to solve it.